# Why does my hash table contain a spurious value?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a hash table to check whether a four-letter word is valid:

```
function myClickHandler(myClickHandler)
{
    var words4=new Array("abed", "abet", "able", "ably", "abut", "aces", "ache", "achy");

    // Initialise hash table
    var wordhash = new Array();

    for (var i in words4)
        {
            wordhash[ words4[i] ] = true;
        };

    var text = wordhash['10'];
}
```

However, when I examine the hash table in a debugger the first element seems to be:

```
wordhash['10'] = true
```

so the final statement in my test function sets the variable text to true. Why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You're doing a few things not completely correct:

- Don't use `for in` for an array.
- With key/value pairs, use an `object`, not an `array`.
- Use `[]` to make arrays, `{}` for objects.
- A `for` loop does not need a trailing `;`.

You could change it into:

```
var words4 = ["abed", "abet", "able", "ably", "abut", "aces", "ache", "achy"];

// Initialise hash table
var wordhash = {};

for (var i = 0; i < words4.length; i++) {
     wordhash[ words4[i] ] = true;
}

console.log(wordhash);
```

What I then get logged is what I think you expect it to be:

```
Object
  abed: true
  abet: true
  able: true
  ably: true
  abut: true
  aces: true
  ache: true
  achy: true
```

Comment: Thank you - with your help I've got my program working; see:

http://www.plasticki.com/show?9EE.

I'd welcome any suggestions for improvements. David

Comment: @johnsondavies: Your code seems very interesting indeed. However, I would not suggest comparing to `undefined` though. Look: `undefined = 1; var a; a == undefined` will yield `false`, because `undefined` is not *really* `undefined` anymore. Instead, use `typeof something == 'undefined'`. Some common practices are also using `===` instead of `==` and `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over an array like this is not a good practice, try checking the value of `i` in the loop. It will give lots of unwanted data.

You better use `i` as an index by making the loop like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<words4.length; i++){
    wordhash[words4[i]] = true;
}
```

In this case when querying `wordhash['10']` it will give `undefined` and when querying anything from the first array like `abed` it will give `true`.